# XSLT for a number xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I've an xml that I need to transform to html, it contains numbers and their parity. I need to create two columns one for even and other for add, but i cannot put it two columns

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="numbers.xsl"?>
<Whole_Numbers>
     <Number>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Parity>odd</Parity>
     </Number>
     <Number>
          <Value>2</Value>
          <Parity>even</Parity>
     </Number>
     <Number>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Parity>odd</Parity>
     </Number>
     <Number>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Parity>even</Parity>
     </Number>
</Whole_Numbers>
```

XSLT -

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Whole Numbers</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr >
      <th>Odd Numbers between 1 and 100</th>
      <th>Even Numbers between 1 and 100</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Whole_Numbers/Number">
    <tr>
     <xsl:if test="contains(Parity, 'odd')">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
     </xsl:if>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>     
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Output -
only odd numbers in odd number column, if i include another td tag it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're definitely alternating odd-even-odd-even like that then you could for-each over just the odd `Number` elements and then use `following-sibling::Number[1]` to get the immediately following even one:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Whole_Numbers/Number[Parity='odd']">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Number[1]/Value"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```